# How do I shut down X in order to install nvidia drivers/looking to install gl.h, glut.h (opengl files)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, opengl

It's astonishingly hard to find out how to install opengl headers on ubuntu. I've seen pointers to the opengl registry: http://www.opengl.org/registry/  but the files do not appear to be there.

I've also see reference that the files come in the nvidia drivers.  Of course, the drivers supposedly are pre-loaded on the distribution, but perhaps not the developer tools.

If anyone on Ubuntu is listening, this is kind of a ludicrous situation.  This is not wildly exotic stuff, loading the graphics libraries should be fast and easy.  In fact, I might venture to suggest that these header files be included with any standard developer headers.

Anyway, I was trying to install the NVIDIA drivers with:

sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-260.19.12.run

This fails because the x server is running.  I want to shut down, but if I kill it, it will just restart.  I tried init 1 and it didn't work.  This seems more complicated than it used to be, but I'm just not used to this distribution, any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look [How to correctly install an Nvidia video card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-correctly-install-an-nvidia-video-card) to know different kind of installation.

If you are keen to use `.run` file.

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Execute `sudo stop lightdm`

Now navigate to the downloaded file directory using `cd`.

Run the .run file using

`sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-260.19.12.run`

`260.19.12` seems pretty old driver, have you checked what is the latest version for your card.

Comment: what about sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Comment: See the link I mentioned, it is mentioned there. apt-get is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch system to lower runlevel. By default, X starts in runlevel 5.
Follow this article: [Debian and Ubuntu Linux Run Levels | Debian Admin](http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html)

you can change runlevel at runtime by executing e.g.`init <n>` or while booting by appending the number of runlevel to the grub boot string.

Comment: Switching `runlevel`s is overkill. A `sudo stop` will do.